# Shuffling word probability

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

The problem states:
We have the word TARANTULA, what is the probability when randomly suffling these letters that we get a sequence containing the word ‘RAT’

My approach was to start with the base case where you put R A T and the remaining 6 letters can be shuffled however so it's 1 * 1 * 1 * 6 * 5 *4 * 3 * 2 * 1. That's how many options there are if RAT is in the beginning. Now, we can 'push' RAT seven times until it reaches the end such as 6 * 5 *4 *3 * 2 *1 * 1 * 1 *1 (the last three letters are RAT).

Therefore the overall probability would be (7 * 6!)/9! which is 1/72 however the correct answer is apparently 1/12. Where did I make a mistake? Thank you!

Comment: But some of the letters repeat and they cannot be swapped within to get new arrangements.

Comment: So number of favorable arrangements are $7! / 2!$, the division by $2!$ is account for two repeating $A$'s once you have $RAT$ as one block of letters.

Comment: Similarly total number of arrangements are $9! / (3! \cdot 2!)$ as there are three $A$'s and two $T$'s

Answer (score 2):

Since others have pointed out the mistake made by the OP (i.e. original poster), it is open season on an alternative approach.

For what it's worth, per the comments of MathLover, immediately following the posting, the problem with the $1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 6 \times 5 \times \cdots \times 2$ computation is that it overlooks that the first $3$ factors should be

$1 \times 3 \times 2$, rather than $1 \times 1 \times 1$, since there are $3$ choices for the "A" and $2$ choices for the "T".

One way of visualizing this approach is to pretend that the $3$ "A"'s are labeled A1, A2, A3 and to pretend that the $2$ "T"'s are labeled T1, T2.

---

This is an unusual problem in that the easiest approach is to compute the probability of specific events, rather than using a Combinatorics approach.

- Let $E_1$ denote the event that the "R" occurs somewhere in the 1st $7$ letters.  
  The probability of this happening is $~\displaystyle \frac{7}{9}.$
- Let $E_2$ denote the event that the letter that immediately follows the "R" is one of the $3$ "A"'s, given that event $E_1$ has occurred  
  The probability of this happening is $~\displaystyle \frac{3}{8}.$
- Let $E_3$ denote the event that the letter that is $2$ places to the right of the "R" is one of the $2$ "T"'s, given that the events $E_1$ and $E_2$ have both occurred.
  The probability of this happening is $~\displaystyle \frac{2}{7}.$

So, the desired computation is

$$\frac{7}{9} \times \frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{7} = \frac{1}{12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using letters of 'TARANTULA' by making that arrangement RAT,T,A,A,N,U,L.

There are one RAT,T,N,U and L

There are two A's

But for the total arrangement

There are three A's

There are two T's

There are one R,N,U and L
Then the probability is
$$P=\large{\frac{7!}{2!}}\large{/}\frac{9!}{2!3!}=\frac{1}{12}$$